# Checkout a git repo and keep updated with only the latest tag

Tags: git, github, git-tag

Is there a way to keep a checkout updated between tags, and only tags?

Ideally, I want to go into the checkout's directory, type "git pull", have the command fail if there are no new tags in the repo **or** pull all the code down from that newer tag.

Is this a bad idea? Maybe, because I can't find a solution, no one actually does this. Are there any issues executing this way?

Comment: `git fetch -a`, parse the output, then checkout the latest tag?

Comment: You can get the necessary data without fetching, `git ls-remote --tags origin` does that, and you can match its format locally with `git for-each-ref refs/tags --format="%(objectname)$(printf '\t')%(refname)"`.

Comment: I looked at fetch and describe, hacked my way around something crappy. ls-remote is super nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following script:

```
git fetch origin
currentTag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
lastTag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/master)
if [ $currentTag != $lastTag ]; then
  git checkout $lastTag;
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you @gturri! I'm not too sure why this question would get down voted.